# PVLIB: tracking system in southern hemisphere

Tags: pvlib

how should be configured a tracking system rotating from East to West installed in the Southern Hemisphere? (tilt = 0)

default functiom

```
pvlib.tracking.SingleAxisTracker(axis_tilt=0, axis_azimuth=0,
                 max_angle=90, backtrack=True, gcr=2.0/7.0)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are there two possibilities?  Just give them a try!

Comment: I would try and first have a look at this tutorial: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/pvlib/pvlib-python/blob/master/docs/tutorials/tracking.ipynb